# Using Nipplejs in Vue with Quasar

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js

i am trying to use Nipplejs in my Vue Project with quasar Components.

I installed nipplejs by `npm install nipplejs --save`.

I tried to integrate the nipple with the following code:

```
<template>
  <div id="joystick_zone"></div>
</template>

<script lang= "ts">
  // Imports
  import Vue from "vue";
  import nipplejs from 'nipplejs';

  export default Vue.extend({
    async mounted(): Promise<void> {
      var options = {
        zone: document.getElementById('joystick_zone') as HTMLElement,
        mode: 'static',
        color: `'blue'`,
      }
      var manager = nipplejs.create(options);
    }
  });
```

My first problem is that typescript doesnt accept 'static' as mode:

The definition says: `mode?: 'dynamic' | 'semi' | 'static';`

And i get the following error message:

> Argument of type '{ zone: HTMLElement; mode: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JoystickManagerOptions'.
> Types of property 'mode' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"dynamic" | "semi" | "static" | undefined'.

My second problem is that the joystick does not appear on the website.

If someone could help i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would look into the definition of `options` variable you created. You would see it is of type `{ zone: HTMLElement; mode: string; color: string; }`.

You must assign a type to the `options` variable.

```
var options: JoystickManagerOptions = {
    zone: document.getElementById('joystick_zone') as HTMLElement,
    mode: 'static',
    color: 'blue',
};
```

Other option is to define the variable as const:

```
var options = {
    zone: document.getElementById('joystick_zone') as HTMLElement,
    mode: 'static',
    color: 'blue',
} as const;

// Variable is now of type
type options = {
    zone: HTMLElementHTMLElement;
    mode: 'static';
    color: 'blue';
}
```